# redirection vs pipe - why it works and why it doesn't

Tags: linux, unix, centos, pipe, redhat

I have an `encrypt()` function that goes like this:

```
encrypt -a aes -k key **-i input.file** -o output.file
```

which take in 1 input file and output 1 file as well.

By using pipe:

```
echo "abc" | encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file
```

Q1) How does the `encrypt()` function know or the OS know that the output for the pipe `|` is suppose to be the input for the encrypt function *(so that i didn't need to specify the "-i input.file" parameter)* ?

Q2 Why does redirection works in this case ?
echo "abc" **>** encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a pipe, conventional files are not involved.  When you invoke

```
echo "abc" | encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file
```

the `encrypt` program does not open a file at all, instead it reads its *standard input*.  The standard input is whatever you set up on the command line when you invoked it.  Standard input can be a pipe, as in your example.  If you use input redirection, standard input can be a file:

```
encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file < otherinput.file
```

Finally, if you don't use any pipes or input redirection at all, that is, if you invoke

```
encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file
```

then the `encrypt` program will read from the keyboard.

Your second question Q2 is meaningless, though.  You will end up creating an output file named "encrypt", and you won't run the `encrypt` program at all.  If you want to use output redirection to control where the `encrypt` program's output goes, you could use

```
encrypt -a aes -k key -i input.file > output.file
```

or

```
echo "abc" | encrypt -a aes -k key > output.file
```

Comment: can you explain why echo "abc" > is not actually providing "abc" as an input to the encrypt process. but yet echo "abc" > file.txt is putting "abc" into the file.txt.

Comment: @Noob `echo "abc"` writes `abc\n` into `stdout`. Because you used the redirection operator to redirect `stdout` to `file.txt`, you are actually writing `abc\n` into a file named  `file.txt`. In general, `echo "X" >Y` will write `X\n` into file `Y`. If you do `echo "abc" > encrypt ...`, you write `abc\n` into a file named `encrypt`. You do not execute the encrypt command.

Comment: When you say `echo abc | encrypt` you are piping the output into the program `encrypt`.  When you say `echo abc > encrypt` you are redirecting the output into a file named "encrypt".  The `|` operator pipes into programs.  The `>` operator redirects to files.  One misunderstanding you may be having is that command names are special in Unix/Linux -- they are not.  When you say `echo abc > encrypt` the shell does **not** notice that "encrypt" is also the name of a command.  It just looks for the word after the `>` and creates an output file by that name.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the explanation. however, if you mean > operator redirect into files. what is the difference between encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file < otherinput.file and echo "abc" > encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file. Both are using redirection.. do you mean > is always meant to redirect to file and < is always use as input to anything ?   or can i just see it this way that redirect always have to deal with file , either output to file > and input from file <

Comment: @Noob: Yes, `>` always redirects output to a file, and `<` always redirects input from a file.  Why do you keep writing `echo "abc" > encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file`, and what do you think it should do?  It sounds like you think that `echo "abc" > encrypt` and `echo "abc" | encrypt ` should do the same thing, but this doesn't make sense, because `>` and `|` are quite different operators.

Comment: @SteveSummit : not sure why, i keep thinking that echo "abc" will redirect "abc" into encrypt function, just like how echo "abc" is being redirected into a file.

Comment: @Noob: `echo "abc"` doesn't redirect anything.  `echo` is a program that takes its command-line arguments and writes them to its _standard output_.  Standard output goes to your screen by default, or to a file if you use `>`, or into another program if you use '|'.

Comment: Try this.  Do `echo "abc" > testfile`.  Now you have a file containing "abc".  Now do (1a) `cat testfile`, (1b) `cat testfile > anotherfile`, (1c) `cat testfile | wc`'.  Notice how the output went (a) to your screen, (b) into another file, and (c) into the `wc` program.  Now type (2a) `echo "abc"`, (2b) `echo "abc" > anotherfile`, (2c) `echo "abc" | wc`'.  Notice how the output went (a) to your screen, (b) into another file, and (c) into the `wc` program.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the examples. what i meant earlier is i keep thinking echo "abc" > will redirect the output of echo into encrypt with the ">" redirection.  i am thinking since > can redirect echo output into a file, why can't it redirect into a program

Comment: Well, let me put it this way.  If (as you seem to still be thinking) `echo "abc" > encrypt` could pipe the output of echo into the `encrypt` program, then if I wanted to take the output of echo and redirect it to a file named "encrypt", how would I do that?  `echo "abc" > encrypt` has to mean either "redirect to a file named 'encrypt'" or "pipe into a program named 'encrypt'"; it can't mean both!

Comment: @SteveSummit you are right. i will just remember that > < is for files and | is for programs

Answer (score 0):

When you type `echo abc | encrypt ...`, the shell reads the entire string and parses it.  It executes `echo` with its stdin set to the stdin of the current shell and its stdout set to the write end of a newly created pipe.  It also forks a copy of `encrypt` and sets its stdin to the read side of that pipe and sets its stdout to the stdout of the shell.  (Note that assigning the stdin of `echo` is a no-op and nothing is actually done, since the stream is simply inherited from the shell.  It is also ignored by `echo`, and if this is confusing please ignore this parenthetical statement.) The OS knows about these associations only in the sense that the internal data structures for each process keep track of the open file descriptors.  In other words, the shell is doing all the work.

Addressing the second question: "Why does redirection works[sic] in this case?", I wonder what you mean when you say it works.  `echo "abc" > encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file` is exactly equvialent to `echo abc -a aes -k key -o output.file > encrypt`, so one would expect the output of echo to be written to a file named `encrypt`, but the `encrypt` command is not executed.

Comment: hi william, are you aslo able to explain why using redirection won't work ?

Comment: Small nitpick: in most shells - bash included - `echo` is a shell builtin, so there's no fork of `echo`, although many systems also have an `echo` binary that works similarly (presumably to make it easy for other shells where `echo` is not builtin, which is rare anyway).

Comment: @william-pursell what i actually meant is why  echo "abc" > encrypt -a aes -k key -o output.file will not work

Comment: @Noob, it doesn't work because you are redirecting the output of `echo abc -a aes -k key -o output.file` to a file named `encrypt`.